# Convert casual string to int in C

Tags: c, string, int

As the title I need to convert a casual string (like "elephant") to a int type. I already know about *atoi* and *strtol* function of *stdlib.h* library. However this ones do not work on casual string (the return value is always 0). Does a function like this exist yet?

Comment: Hm. So what is an `int` value of elephant ?

Comment: @EugeneSh. [0x1F418](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F418) obviously.

Comment: @tadman Lol. I didn't see it coming :)

Comment: @xing I would take base 256 to be on the safe side. Unfortunately `strtol` doesn't support it...

Comment: @xing or even `strtoll()`,  "elephant" gives `1143700050233` but even that will not be big enough for "tyrannosaurus" which is `141987995361270070000`.

Comment: What's the `int` value of `"a"`? Of `"-aa"`? Of `"a-a"`? Of `"aa-"`? Of `"1"`? Of `"pi"`? Of `"e=mc2"`?

Comment: If OP gives a few examples I think this should be reopened, since it seems like he just wants to map some strings to ints following some sort of basic pattern (of course, we can't tell currently what that pattern is)

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for a simple string hash function? Like perhaps FNV?

Answer (score 1):

What `atoi` does is convert "integer strings" into integer values. This is the opposite of `itoa`.

The string `"elephant"` has no numerical meaning. If you wanted to encode it in an `int` you'd need an 8-byte integer and an [endian convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) to follow. Any longer strings would need to be split into multiple integer values.

Obviously the utility of this is rather dubious as what advantage does this have over byte arrays?

So the short answer is there is no function because there's no encoding of arbitrary strings into integers. Remember there's only 2<sup>32</sup> or 2<sup>64</sup> possible integer values on most platforms, but 2<sup>2<sup>36</sup></sup> possible string values on a typical modern computer.

You can't map 2<sup>68719476736</sup> possible string values (e.g. 8GB) into a 2<sup>64</sup> integer.

If you did want to map arbitrary words to numbers you'd need a look-up table, such as a dictionary, that assigned a pre-defined integer value to each possible input word. As no such list of words exists, the exhaustive list is far too big, and there's no standard as to what number elephant has, emoji notwithstanding, this is something you'd have to make yourself.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I meant the other one. Editing.

Answer (score 0):

You could always compare the strings using `strncmp`.

So something like

```
int strParse(char * str){   
  if(strncmp(str,"elephant",8) == 0) return 42;
  return 0;
 }
```

...and so on. Just keep in mind that this takes time.

Comment: Like... *Every* "casual" string?

Comment: Like every one in his application? Maybe? Depends how many he has.